# Debugging individual sections in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging

I have a question that I have been wondering about for some time, regarding debugging.

Lets say I have a hugh code divided into sections

```
%%Initialise section
Load Data

%%Analyse Data
%%Plot Data
%%Data Manipulation
```

I can easily run the individual sections by the interface or using ´ctrl+enter´. But what if I also want to debug the individual section?

I know it is possible by either running the entire code, create a function that you call from another editor or simply commenting the before made code out. But it would be nice if I could debug individual sections. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you debug normally? Because it's possible to, for example, put the `keyboard` command in individual sections...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes of course that is a solution, did not think of that. I normally use breakpoints, such that I can step through the code. This gives a better control of the debugging than just manually putting  keyboard waits in the code.

Comment: Yup. I also dislike having to explicitly put debug code in. Breakpoints are just so much cleaner. Ctrl+Enter in a cell (or F9 on selection) basically means "Copy-paste the contents of the cell in the Command Windows, and execute". From that point of view, breakpoints are of course impossible.

Comment: I can understand your kine of thinking, but for me it could be possible, but maybe not user friendly. Since you might get errors from code that had not been done earliere. But still had hoped :)

Comment: @JTIM As of MATLAB 2015a putting keyboard in an individual section and running the section will cause the terminal to get stuck in a "Waiting for Input" mode. (Just FYI execute "return" from the terminal to get out of this mode, Ctrl+C won't do it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I sometimes do is use block comments in a "smart" way:

```
function myFunction

    %% section 1
    %{

    code here
    more code here

   %}

   %% Section 2
   %{

    code here
    more code here

   %}

end
```

Comment everything out by default, except the necessary initialization stuff, and the section of interest of course. The easiest way to comment stuff back in is to put a space in the block comment's start marker:

```
%{
'This is a valid block comment, and this string is commented out';
%} 

% {
'This is now UNcommented, because the start marker is now an ordinary comment';
%}
```

Executing the function will then allow you to use breakpoints normally.

Comment: I feel that is a bit the same as marking everything and pressing control+r and control+t. But it is a solution